# :after and :before pseudo-element selectors in Sass

Tags: css, css-selectors, sass, pseudo-element

How can I use the :before and :after pseudo-element selectors following the syntax of Sass or, alternatively, SCSS? Like this:

```
p
  margin: 2em auto
  > a
    color: red
  :before
    content: ""
  :after
    content: "* * *"
```

Of course, the above fails.

Comment: @cimmanon Actually, the question "Sass .scss: Nesting and multiple classes?" is duplicated, because it was asked after a month of this one

Comment: Age is not how we determine duplicates.  The other question is a more general version of this question, which is why it was closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 518, accepted):

[Use ampersand to specify the parent selector](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector).

SCSS syntax:

```
p {
    margin: 2em auto;

    > a {
        color: red;
    }

    &:before {
        content: "";
    }

    &:after {
        content: "* * *";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it apply to all pseudo class and element?