# How to use pseudo selectors like ::before in vuejs scoped style

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuejs3, scoped

Consider below styles:

```
<template>
  <!-- Some Tags -->

 <div class="mb-8 w-full">
   <span class="subline"></span>
 </div>

</template>

.
.
.


<style scoped lang="scss">

.subline {
  border-bottom: dashed 2px #eee;
  display: block;
}

.subline::before { /* Not working ! */
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 99999;
  border-bottom: dashed 2px green;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
</style>
```

I need to use `::before` but does not working !

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [:after and :before pseudo-element selectors in Sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750563/after-and-before-pseudo-element-selectors-in-sass)

Comment: @bassxzero No, I don't have problem with `sass` syntax. I need `::before` in scoped style in vuejs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pseudo elements require a `content` property to be visible, add `content: ""` to solve this issue

```
.subline::before {
  content: "";
  width: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 99999;
  border-bottom: dashed 2px green;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I really had forgotten that